# Why does this apparently superfluous join fix my query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Whilst reformulating a problem query, I stumbled on the fact that an apparently superfluous join fixed it. I do not understand why. (I have difficulty explaining succinctly; please bear with me. The business context - reports and their parameters - is not important.)

I have three tables that hold the history of calls to various reports, including parameters passed into the report. Report parameter values are always stored as strings, in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImportReportParameter](
[ImportReportParameterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ImportReportHistoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ParameterName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[ParameterValue] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
…
```

All reports accept a date range so I know that for each ImportReportHistoryID there is a single ImportReportParameter row whose ParamaterName is “RangeStart” and one whose ParameterName is “RangeEnd”. I know that the ParameterValue strings in these rows can be safely cast as DateTime. 
The query at issue flattens the data to yield a single row per report instance containing the date range as a pair of DateTimes:

```
select top (@numberToRetrieve) ir.*,
    (select cast(ParameterValue as datetime) from ImportReportParameter iparm where iparm.ImportReportHistoryID = ir.ImportReportHistoryID and ParameterName = 'RangeStart') RangeStart,
    (select cast(ParameterValue as datetime) from ImportReportParameter iparm where iparm.ImportReportHistoryID = ir.ImportReportHistoryID and ParameterName = 'RangeEnd') RangeEnd
from  ImportReportHistory ir 
order by Requested desc
```

This has all been working fine for a while. But then the query started failing with:

> > Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> >
> > Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I assumed bad data had got into a ParameterValue field but confirmed this was not the case by successfully executing :

```
select ImportReportHistoryID, cast(ParameterValue as datetime) RangeStart 
from ImportReportParameter 
where ParameterName = 'RangeStart'
```

and, similarly:

```
select ImportReportHistoryID, cast(ParameterValue as datetime) RangeEnd 
from ImportReportParameter 
where ParameterName = 'RangeEnd'
```

I then started varying @numberToRetrieve and things got weird. For values up to 46 the query works but I couldn’t see anything wrong with the 47th instance… I tried running for just the 47th instance and it was fine. I then removed the “desc” from the order by and that worked too, up to the first 46 of them. *But there are only 80 rows in my test ImportReportHistory data set.* So I *can* safely retrieve *all* of the records with this query: there isn’t a problem with the data in any of them. It doesn’t matter which ones I retrieve, so long as I only retrieve up to 46 of them. Which I think is weird.

Unable to figure it out I decided to reformulate to use joins to the parameter table instead and realised that just adding the apparently entirely superfluous join fixes things:

```
…
from  ImportReportHistory ir 
    left join ImportReportParameter pSuperfluous on ir.ImportReportHistoryID = pSuperfluous.ImportReportHistoryID
```

So my question is: why does the superfluous join “fix” a query which, so far as I can see, should have worked anyway?

Edit: actually it doesn't fix it because I now get multiple rows per ImportReportHistoryID - I'm sorting that out now - but it solves the cast issue.

Edit (2): the superfluous join did not really fix it, it just made it occur less frequently. I have now reformulated the query thus:

```
select top (@numberToRetrieve) ir.*, t.DisplayName, 
    p1.RangeStart, 
    p2.RangeEnd,
from  ImportReportHistory ir 
    left join ImportReportTemplate t on ir.ImportReportTemplateID = t.ImportReportTemplateID
    left join (select ImportReportHistoryID, cast(ParameterValue as datetime) RangeStart from ImportReportParameter where ParameterName = 'RangeStart') p1 on p1.ImportReportHistoryID = ir.ImportReportHistoryID
    left join (select ImportReportHistoryID, cast(ParameterValue as datetime) RangeEnd from ImportReportParameter where ParameterName = 'RangeEnd') p2 on p2.ImportReportHistoryID = ir.ImportReportHistoryID
order by Requested desc
```

Which is working for now but:

The answer to my original question seems to lie in the discussion Martin pointed me to in the comments, about the order in which SELECT and WHERE are processed. As I understand it, the select *can* be processed before the where, which is why it is *sometimes* attempting to cast ParameterValue as DateTime for a row whose ParameterName is not RangeStart or RangeEnd. This is giving unpredictable results and seems to contravene the logical processing order documented by Microsoft. It also means that my reformulated query (and others I've authored in that past) could fail some day, so it's not yet a satisfactory solution.

Comment: When you left Join are you seeing any rows with Null values, if so, that is why it fixed it as its including everything from ImportReportParameter regardless if it's key is found in your join.

Comment: Please show us sample data. If you do  `select ImportReportHistoryID, ParameterValue
from ImportReportParameter 
where ParameterName = 'RangeStart'  order by ParameterValue` do you see anything weird at begin or end?

Comment: The two queries you show after the error works as expected or also generate the same error?

Comment: you are making assumptions about order of execution that aren't safe in practice (that the where will execute before the cast in the select) https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Comment: Ryan, I have many rows where the ParameterValue is null but the cast yields null datetimes for these as expected. Every row in the ImportReportHistory has at least two rows in the parameter table - one each for RangeStart and RangeEnd, so the left join does not expose any additional rows.

Comment: Juan Carlos, the two checking queries both work.

Comment: Martin, I've tried it with and without the where clause, and I've checked that none of the ImportReportParameter rows has bad data in it, so I can't see how ordering assumptions are affecting me??

Comment: The query you give in your question `confirmed this was not the case by successfully executing :` both have `where` clauses. Try without the `where`

Comment: OK Martin, sorry, I was confused and now see what you mean. No, those queries won't work without their where clauses because other parameters are held in ImportReportParameters, with names other than "RangeStart" and "RangeEnd", whose values cannot be converted to date times.

Comment: Hello again Martin, it looks like it is the issue discussed in the link you showed me (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). If this is the problem, then I’m humbly with the those over in that discussion who call it a bug, because of the inconsistency and because MS do indeed say themselves that logically the WHERE comes before the SELECT over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 .

Comment: Yes, if you can reformulate your query to only perform conversions within appropriately guarded `THEN` clauses of `CASE` expressions and avoid aggregates, it may work. The 100% safe method is to split apart your query (totally against usual advice) and first extract values that will be safe to convert into a table variable and *then* do the conversion in a second query. Most of "the people" calling it a bug (Beyond Erland who raised the issue) were me :-)